# Can't hide <li> element in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

List categories:

```
<ul class="list">
<li data-value="" class="option selected focus">All Categories</li>
<li data-value="5058" class="option">Cat 1</li>
<li data-value="5064" class="option">Cat 2</li>
<li data-value="5121" class="option">Cat 3</li>
<li data-value="6151" class="option" style="display: list-item;">Cat 4</li>
<li data-value="6379" class="option"></li>
<li data-value="6758" class="option">Cat 6</li></ul>
```

I removed `<li data-value="6379" class="option"></li>` List from Wordpress Dashboard and now i get this:

[How is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQPfC.png)

I try to hide that with CSS:

```
1. ul.list li.option:nth-of-type(5n+0) {display: none !important;}
2. ul.list li.option:nth-child(5) {
   display:none;
}
3.ul.list li.option:nth-of-type(1n+4) {display: none;}
```

How to remove that field from the dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, you needed nth-child(6) because its the 6th item!!

```css
ul.list .option:nth-child(6) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li data-value="" class="option selected focus">All Categories</li>
  <li data-value="5058" class="option">Cat 1</li>
  <li data-value="5064" class="option">Cat 2</li>
  <li data-value="5121" class="option">Cat 3</li>
  <li data-value="6151" class="option" style="display: list-item;">Cat 4</li>
  <li data-value="6379" class="option"></li>
  <li data-value="6758" class="option">Cat 6</li></ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have same issue

Comment: The code snippet above works if you run it. This therefore means that you have something else thats overriding your style. Try adding !important to disp[lay like display:none!important;